# Laravel how to filter out and get available doctors based on leave

Tags: laravel

I have a method to let users to choose a date from a selected month where it will exclude out any dates found in my holiday tables.

I want to further filter it out by checking my leaves table for the selected day to find out which doctors are available for booking selection for that selected date (e.g. 28 May). E.g. Doctor A will be on leave from 27 May - 28 May, Doctor B does not have a leave data table entry. My current codes below is able to get for this scenario. But for the case of where e.g. Both Doctor A and B are on leave on the 28 May, I will get an error

> Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined

Below are the codes I have tried out:

```php
private function checkLeave($selecteddate)
{
    $leave = Leave::where('clinic_id', '=', $_SESSION['clinic_ID'])
        ->where('start_date', '<=', $selecteddate)
        ->where('end_date', '>=' , $selecteddate)->pluck('doctor_id');

    $leavesList = DB::table('leaves')
        ->join('accounts', 'accounts.accountID', '=', 'leaves.doctor_id')
        ->where('leaves.clinic_id', '=', $_SESSION['clinic_ID'])
        ->where('leaves.doctor_id', '!=' ,$leave)->pluck('name', 'doctor_id');
    
    return $leavesList;
}
```

Below are my current methods on filtering out the available dates for appointment:

```php
private function getSelectedMonth($select_month)
{
    $holidays = $this->getHolidays();
    $results = [];
    $mthselected = Carbon::parse($select_month);
    $workinghr = WorkingHour::where('clinic_id', $_SESSION['clinic_ID'])
        ->where('off_day', false)
        ->pluck('day')->toArray();

    $firstDayOfMth = $mthselected->startOfMonth()->format('Y-m-d');
    $lastDayOfMth = $mthselected->endOfMonth()->format('Y-m-d');

    $today = Carbon::now('Asia/Singapore');
    $todayMonth = $today->format('M Y');
    $mthOfSelected = $mthselected->format('M Y');

    if($mthOfSelected == $todayMonth) {
        $todayf = $today->format('Y-m-d');
        $dateRange = CarbonPeriod::create($todayf, $lastDayOfMth);
        foreach ($dateRange as $date) {
            $name = $date->format('l');
            if (in_array($name, $workinghr)
                && !in_array($date->format('Y-m-d'), $holidays)) {
                    $results[] = ' '. $date->format('d M Y');
            }
        }
    } else {
        $dateRange = CarbonPeriod::create($firstDayOfMth, $lastDayOfMth);
        foreach ($dateRange as $date) {
            $name = $date->format('l');
            if (in_array($name, $workinghr)
                && !in_array($date->format('Y-m-d'), $holidays)) {  
                    $results[] = ' '. $date->format('d M Y');     
            }
        }   
    }
            
    return $results;
}
```

Is there a way where I can better filter out and check whether the selected date have available doctors?

Comment: I believe the $leave variable will be a collection and contain multiple values if there are multiple results. You would need to rework your $leavesList query to check for that. Do you know what party of your query is throwing the error?

Comment: I think its my $leaveList where my $leave gets 2 doctor ID which is the total of doctors I have for the clinic, I will get the error